# I want to save data in local storage first and later sync it to cloud database by Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hi I want to save data locally when app is offline, as the button click, and sync later on when network available.

I am using saveEventually() by parse but, unable to save data on button click.

Note. As I click button it do two function, first save the data and secondly open the second activity. And it will also, intent objectId in new activity.

`public void nextQues(View view){
        final ProgressDialog pdia = new ProgressDialog(StartFeedback.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading Ques 2...Please wait...");
        pdia.show();`

```
    final ParseObject newUser = new ParseObject("ArtofLiving");
    newUser.put("happinessIndex", textView.getText().toString());
    newUser.put("userName", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    newUser.pinInBackground();
    newUser.saveEventually(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                String objectId = newUser.getObjectId();
                pdia.dismiss();
                StartFeedback.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartFeedback.this, QuesTwo.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", objectId);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(StartFeedback.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pdia.dismiss();
                StartFeedback.this.finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartFeedback.this, GreyGreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?

Comment: The toast message keep on loading...

Comment: So the problem is a toast message appearing repeatedly?  Or something to do with saving data?